# Cloning sections using Metalclone putting all new items into the wrong section

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I have a page that contains multiple sections and then within each section, there are a few rows of form fields (name, age, gender, etc.). Generic stuff. Below each section is a button to add a new row. The problem is when any of the buttons are depressed, the newly clone row will append to the very last section and not the section that corresponds to the one the button was clicked for.

When you click the "Create new element" button in the "Close Friends" section and then scroll down to the Frienimes section and you'll see the newly added row there.

Here is a link to the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/SavageCatHV/t7Lyppja/).

The plugin supports a destination value but I won't know what that is ahead of time so I'm hoping I could setup a data attribute and then pass that into the plugin but I dont' know how to do that.

One of the examples shows the destination as an example:

```
$('.toClone_example6').metalClone({
    position            : 'after',
    destination         : '.toClone_example6_destination'
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm the creator of this plugin and you're the one who open the issue from github, am i right?

To cater this situation, you must initialise `metalClone` call for each sections to clone and use different class name for each section.

See updated demo here [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/norlihazmeyGhazali/hpnyjqL2/).

At the same time, i'll fix this issue and will add another features for next release. Stay tuned.

Comment: I was on my mobile earlier; when I got to the computer and looked at the  jsFiddle you posted, you added additional selectors. While that does work, I wont know what the selectors are ahead of time. So while your solution does answer my original question, I'll need to wait for the next release for this feature. Fingers crossed! You still rock though! :)

Comment: Orite, that issue already fixed. But there are still some feature i still working on. Wait for it :) Thanks